# Azure Keyvault Sign API - Response body “value” encoding format

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

When I do a post request to the Azure Key Vault Sign API: `https://pkitstencryptkeyvault.vault.azure.net/keys/openssl-rbi-test/1ccc8fc0e0224bb1a65eb159e2b12df1/sign?api-version=7.0`
with body:

```
{
    "alg": "ES256",
    "value": "RkQ4y5rDgxeaaOzeqeAFT3IGLAEZMz2ztbTbMNzxuMc"
}
```

The response is:

```
{
    "kid": "https://pkitstencryptkeyvault.vault.azure.net/keys/openssl-rbi-test/1ccc8fc0e0224bb1a65eb159e2b12df1",
    "value": "d9J4G06FRMBEKy_FJJj1PEAXhtlezvd6-3_5yo9yeYAFZ_Du583AJzqu3NMTzJAUMoKhnVBx2obnkM0gI1LnoQ"
}
```

I can't find that information on the [Azure Sign API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/sign/sign#examples).

> So what is the format of the value in the response body?

I'm asking this, because when I send a verify request to:
`https://pkitstencryptkeyvault.vault.azure.net/keys/openssl-rbi-test/1ccc8fc0e0224bb1a65eb159e2b12df1/verify?api-version=7.0` with body:

```
{
    "alg": "ES256",
    "value": "d9J4G06FRMBEKy_FJJj1PEAXhtlezvd6-3_5yo9yeYAFZ_Du583AJzqu3NMTzJAUMoKhnVBx2obnkM0gI1LnoQ"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadParameter",
        "message": "Property  has invalid value\r\n"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the example does not show it: The digest parameter is missing in your verify request body. This parameter is defined in the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/verify/verify).